# Padding breakpoints in MUI5 sx props

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm refactoring some components to use the latest MUI version.
As so, I'm often "translating" old classes into the `sx` props and I found myself enjoying this new way of styling which is more readable imho.

One thing aches me though, I couldn't find how to handle breakpoints in the `sx` props while still leveraging the `theme.spacing()` mapping.

I had this basic class that was styling a div with some padding :

```js
// old class
titleContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    [breakpoints.up("lg")]: { padding: spacing(3, 5, 2) },
    [breakpoints.down("lg")]: { padding: spacing(2, 2, 1) },
    [breakpoints.down("sm")]: { padding: spacing(2, 1, 1) },
  },
```

Now I have this `Box` :

```js
<Box
  display="flex"
  alignItems="center"
  sx={{
    padding: {
      xs: theme.spacing(2, 1, 1),
      md: theme.spacing(2, 2, 1),
      lg: theme.spacing(3, 5, 2),
      },
  }}
>
```

This works fine, but with the latest MUI update we often don't need to use `theme.spacing()` anymore, and this array notation would work as well :

`sx={{ p: 2 }}` OR `sx={{ p: [2,1] }}`

But the same notation is not recognize when used for a breakpoints which I don't get, and that forces me to either use `strings` (and computed `px` values) or `theme.spacing()`.

It's not that important, but I'd like to understand why and how can I improve this.

Cheers!

---

**EDIT**
*I just realized that having `p: [2, 1]` doesn't translate to `padding: 16px 8px;` as I initially thought. The array is a shorthand to breakpoints : `p: [2, 1] == p: {xs: 2, sm: 1}`*

*While that clears things up a little bit, I'm still unsure about the "cleanest" way to define a more complex padding with breakpoints.
From what I understand it would be something like :*

```js
sx:{{
  pt: [2,1],
  px: 2,
  pb: [2,3],
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the breakpoints inside the css property.
for different padding at different sides you need to use proper css property like `p, pl, pr, pt, pb, px, py` for all supported css properties in sx props please check https://mui.com/system/properties/

```
sx={{ 
  p: { xs: 2, md: 4, lg: 6 }, // for all sides
  px: { xs: 2, md: 4, lg: 6 }, // for left and right side
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but yea I know that since I provided an example with breakpoints.

My issue is when I have a more complex padding (like say (2, 4)) AND breakpoints.

Comment: I think you cannot add multiple values to padding however you can use different padding properties with single value inside it.